# Rsync, remove source files, symlink

Tags: shell-script, rsync, symlink

Need help with this one. I am trying to move some folders from source to destination with error handling (because mv failed to close files looking at rsync now) so far this is what I have. But it’s not deleting source after copy to destination, as well as not excluding folders from list, and not symlinking (I think because the folder did not get deleted)

Goal:

- Copy folders then delete at source
- Exclude some folders with list
- Do not copy symlinks
- Create symlink after copy and delete has completed for each folder.

Attempt:

```
rsync --remove-source-files --safe-links --exclude-from=/scripts/files2keep.txt
-rptgo /test/ /destest && ln -s /destest/ /test/
```